# Is there a way to import an Excel module (VBA) from a network location?

Tags: excel, vba, module

Is there a way to import a whole module of subs/functions into an excel workbook upon open?  The idea is to have older workbooks import newer code when opened without the need to always go into Develop tab and paste new code in.

The code is currently in a *.txt file.

I figured it out thanks to  Mathieu Guindon:

```
Private Sub Auto_Open()
  CreateModule "Module2", "your\file\path.txt"
End Sub


Public Sub CreateModule(ByRef ModuleName As String, ByRef CodeFileName As String)

  Const vbext_ct_StdModule = 1
  Dim vbComp As Object
  Set vbComp = ModuleName
  Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents.Add(vbext_ct_StdModule)
  vbComp.Name = ModuleName
  vbComp.CodeModule.AddFromFile (CodeFileName)

End Sub
```

Comment: If you have to update the module, why can't you just update the whole workbook?

Comment: Is the code a standard module? a class module? a form? some worksheet's code-behind?

Comment: `Set component = Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents.Add(vbext_ct_StdModule)` to add a new std module, then `component.CodeModule.AddFromFile(path)` to load the text file. Requires a reference to the VBE Extensibility API, which requires explicit trusting of the VBIDE API, which allows the VBE to execute code that modifies and generates code, which may or may not be something your IT department will be ok with. Not sure it supports UNC paths though.

Comment: I can update the module of each, but there are dozens of different workbooks used by different users that all use the same code.  It's very tedious to do so every time there's an update or bug fix.

Comment: Thanks Mathieu, I will try that.  Does it replace my module, or add to it?

Comment: `Add` typically adds, yes. Look at the members of `CodeModule` available to use in the VBIDE API. Feel free to [edit] your post to include a [mcve] with an actual specific question!

Comment: I figured it out, worked perfectly (even on  a network!).  Updated post to include answer as well.  Thanks again!